# Finding weak form of equation with two different functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives, finite-element-method

There are two different functions f and g in an equation. I would like to make this equation into a weak formulation.

$$
\nabla^2f+\nabla^2 \ln g + a=0
$$

For example, if this equation is defined in x dimension, how can I make this to weak form? I'm not sure if there are two different test functions needed for each function. Please feel free to set a convenient boundary condition for solving

Answer (score 1):

First you multiply your equation with a test function $w$ and integrate over your domain $\Omega$ on which your problem is defined
$$
\int_\Omega (\nabla^2f + \nabla^2 \ln g + a)\cdot w \ d\Omega= 0.
$$
Specify the functionspace for $\mathcal{V}$ for $w$. A common choice woule be a first order Sobolev space, with the test function being zero on the boundary $\partial \Omega$
$$
\mathcal{V} = \mathcal{H}^1_0 = \{ w \in L^2(\Omega): w(\partial\Omega)=0, \nabla w \in L^2(\Omega) \}.
$$
What you can do now is split up the weak formulation into its summands, so you can treat each term individually
$$
\int_\Omega \nabla^2f \cdot w \ d\Omega  + \int_\Omega \nabla^2 (\ln g) \cdot w \ d \Omega + \int_\Omega a \cdot w \ d\Omega= 0.
$$
Now the name of the game is pretty straight forward. Apply integration by parts to every term, where your functions such as $f$ have more than just a first order derivative and move it to the test function. You probably have seen how it is done for the first term including $f$, since it appears in the Laplace (sometimes also called Poisson) equation, so you get
$$
\int_\Omega \nabla^2f \cdot w \ d\Omega = \int_\Omega \nabla f \cdot \nabla w\ d\Omega.
$$
The last term including $a$ can be left as it is, since no derivative of $a$ appears at all. I'm not sure about the term in the middle, but I would guess that you treat $\ln g$ the same way as $f$. So you should get in total
$$
\int_\Omega \nabla f \cdot \nabla w\ d\Omega + \int_\Omega \nabla (\ln g) \cdot \nabla w\ d\Omega + \int_\Omega a \cdot w\ d\Omega = 0.
$$

Comment: I wondered if the test function should be different for each f and g because f and g are different functions. I thought this way because I found the test function was defined with a specified variable when I applied this in COMSOL.
For example, in terms of weak formulation of the Poisson equation in 1D, the syntax is 
-test(ux)*ux+f*test(u). test function must be defined for a specific variable.
Since the equation in this thread has two variables, I thought it needed two different test functions for each variable.

Comment: I am quite sure that you have to apply the same test function for each function. Otherwise your weak formulation is not related anymore to the strong form. You can however apply different test functions when you have a coupled system of differential equations, for example such as in the Stokes or Navier-Stokes equations, where you apply the same test function within each separate equation, but you can use different  test functions for the momentum and mass balance.